# Ratio in groups in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I'd like help getting the ratio of two groups in a dataframe that has multiple indexes (or what I think are multiple indexes). I pasted a small sample  of the dataframe in a dictionary below.

What I'd like is to get the ratio of group 'Basal' to 't2' per user for the value variable 'Tristeza Aparente'. So, for example, for user 21, the ratio is 4 (4 at basal and 1 at t2). In this dataframe, each user is either in placebo or the treatment group and has two rows at each time period.

So, the specific question is: how do I create a new column per user that gets the ratio of the value between time periods? I''m a little new to multi-indexing in Pandas and couldn't quite figure out how get a function of different values between groups. I looked at other Stackoverflow questions on this topic and my circumstances were different. (Eventually, I'll do a groupby comparing placebo to treatment, but right now I just want to be able to get the ratio per user).

Thank you and let me know if there are any questions!

```
{'01. Tristeza Aparente': {0: 4.0,
  1: 4.0,
  2: 4.0,
  4: 1.0,
  41: 4.0,
  42: 2.0,
  43: 4.0,
  44: 1.0},
 'groupedit': {0: 'placebo',
  1: 'placebo',
  2: 'placebo',
  4: 'placebo',
  41: 'treatment',
  42: 'treatment',
  43: 'treatment',
  44: 'treatment'},
 'subjectedit': {0: 1.0,
  1: 1.0,
  2: 2.0,
  4: 3.0,
  41: 20.0,
  42: 20.0,
  43: 21.0,
  44: 21.0},
 'testday': {0: 'Basal',
  1: 't2',
  2: 'Basal',
  4: 'Basal',
  41: 'Basal',
  42: 't2',
  43: 'Basal',
  44: 't2'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can aggregate the data by user with a `pivot_table` called `piv`, making `basal` and `t2` into columns, so that you can divide these coleumns by each other to get the desired ratio
2. Then, perform the desired calculation
3. Finally, merge the result back into the original dataframe

---

```
piv = df.pivot_table(index=['subjectedit', 'groupedit'], columns=['testday'],
                     values=['01. Tristeza Aparente'], aggfunc='sum').reset_index().droplevel(1, axis=1)
piv['new'] = piv.iloc[:,-2] / piv.iloc[:,-1]
df = pd.merge(df,piv[['subjectedit', 'groupedit','new']], how='left', on=['subjectedit', 'groupedit'])
df
Out[1]: 
   01. Tristeza Aparente  groupedit  subjectedit testday  new
0                    4.0    placebo          1.0   Basal  1.0
1                    4.0    placebo          1.0      t2  1.0
2                    4.0    placebo          2.0   Basal  NaN
3                    1.0    placebo          3.0   Basal  NaN
4                    4.0  treatment         20.0   Basal  2.0
5                    2.0  treatment         20.0      t2  2.0
6                    4.0  treatment         21.0   Basal  4.0
7                    1.0  treatment         21.0      t2  4.0
```